# how to set text in loader

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I use support-v4.jar , and can be easily show the loader.
 But I want to set some text beside the circle.
and what should i do ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. Place a `ProgressBar` with a `TextView` in the xml layout.
2. Use a `ProgressDialog` and call `setMessage()`

Comment: thanks for your answer,but the same as @Chirag Raval.i want to use AsyncTaskLoader.not  ProgressDialog .

Comment: `AsyncTaskLoader` is for loading data for an Activity in a background thread.`ProgressDialog` is a UI component showing progress of any operation. I doubt there's anything common in them to replace each other's functionality.

Comment: not replace,but to change the UI style . use the AsyncTaskLoader in ListFragment have a default circle , I just want to set the circle style . not use a ProgressBar to replace AsyncTaskLoader's loadInbackground.
You not tried to use the Support-v4.jar, and no ProgressBar case?

Comment: `ListFragment` has method `setListShown()`, which you can use to show/hide it. When It's hidden it will show a progress circle instead. That's the way `ListFragment` is created to behave.

Comment: Well, The `ListFragment` is more of a utility class that auto-generates layout for you and it only generates one kind of layout.  So, if you need some thing custom , Use a normal fragment and create your own layout.